# Can I dynamically load HTML string as a component template and fully compile it in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

So I read this: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

I am trying to load product description pages from i18n database.
Let's define REST Server which e.g. request:

```
{ product: "stick", lang: "en" }
```

Will return:

```
{ content:
   "<div class="wrap">
        <h1>English translation title</h1>
        <span>Some text</span>
        <app-image-component some-component-bindings="..."></app-image-component>
    </div>"
  css:
   ".wrap { rules }"
}
```

My questions:

- (based on tutorial link) I know Angular allows pulling data objects and inserting them to predefined html template. Does is allow inserting whole template (whole HTML, not just data values)?
- Is custom css also allowed? I know css (or sass) is compiled into Angular-specific "thingy" - can this be done when it is loaded? What about inlined css?
- If 1st is possible - will it also compile angular things (app-defined components such as `app-image-component` in example)?

Goal is to give admin (of app) power to put together product content pages that can use pre-defined components filled with data.

Is what I am trying to do well-supported or will it be very complicated (with some weird tricks)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible and can be still usable in production builds.

You can build whole application AOT and then dynamically load module that uses angular compiler library. This keeps base of app small (you app + few kB to handle dynamic loading) and loads compiler when needed that weights something around 300kB.

After `build --prod` and gzip it comes down to less than 80kB for compiler alone. This is something you can live with if you plan on having fully dynamic pages.

I won't write code here, but:

See "Creating components on the fly"

https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e

Mini app (needs refining for dynamic modules):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-app-init-zyns9l

`4.hash.js` is dynamically loaded chunk with compiler.

[image]

EDIT

Additional very important link:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9306#issuecomment-435404174

Angular will drop your decorators (everything with @) when it compiles (AOT). If you want to preserve them for JIT part of your app, you need to reexport them (everyone you use). Basically you want to drop them everywhere where AOT compiles, but preserve them in sub-module (lazy loaded), by making reexports that prevent angular from stripping them and then webpack from treeshaking them from build, which would result in compiler to be unable to compile them JIT (since it needs them to do so).

Comment: All three points in your question, i did in one of my project. Not just template, the whole logics came from a database at run time. The binding between template and logic also worked perfectly between template and logic. It is true i had to use JIT but with proper lazy loading and gzipping, minification, uglification and tree shaking, all my bundle sizes combined were 350KB. It was a very large scale project with atleast 50 components and 20 services in the bundle. Let me know if you still want to know about it

Comment: @NabilShahid I revisited lazy loading modules and managed to do above (updated whole answer). Did you reach any better results when it comes to size (is your 350kB before gzip?!)? Please share if you did better :)

Comment: Yes, lazing loading the module that uses compiler and gzipping are the main things here to achieve fast load. You did it right. Mine was 350KB after gzipping combining all js files. There is one another thing you might wanna look at that is "preloadAllModules" in angular. What it does is, when your first chunk loads, i.e. main.hash.js in your case, the applications starts working and the rest of the chunks keep loading in the background. Which means that instead of loading the next module when you visit that page, it is already loaded. It might be useful as well for u

Comment: I added one more edit with thing that is needed (I think). Let's hope Ivy (new engine) will solve all out JIT problems soon. :)